# Sacar otro registro relacionado de una misma tabla en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

¿Es posible sacar de una misma tabla un registro que esta asociado en esa misma tabla?

Paso a explicarlo mejor:

**Mi tabla de clientes**

| id | name | centro | asociado_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nombre1 | Centro hair remove |  |
| 2 | nombre2 | Centro estética | 1 |

**Mi tabla equipos**

| id | nombre | cliente_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | equipo 600w | 1 |
| 2 | equipo 800w | 2 |

Tengo una tabla de clientes y hay clientes que pueden estar asociados a otros, por algunos motivos los he tenido que meter en la misma tabla, en lugar de una tabla distinta. Lo que estoy haciendo es iterar todos los equipos que tienen un equipo, del siguiente modo:

```
$equipos = Equipo::leftjoin('clientes', 'equipos.cliente_id', '=', 'clientes.id')
                            ->leftjoin('modelos', 'equipos.referencia', '=', 'modelos.id' )
                            ->select('equipos.*', 'clientes.name AS nombreCliente', 'clientes.apellidos', 'clientes.empresa', 'clientes.id AS idCliente', 'modelos.modelo AS refeEquipo', 'modelos.foto')
                            ->get();
```

**Luego los datos los itero en una datatable**

```
<table id="equipos" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th class="thnueva" width="50">Fech. Adquirido</th>
       <th class="thnueva center">Foto</th>
       <th class="thnueva">Referencia</th>
       <th class="thnueva">Nombre</th>
       <th class="thnueva center">NºSerie</th>
       <th class="thnueva center">Estado</th>
       <th class="thnueva">Cliente</th>
       <th class="thnueva">Distribuidor</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       @foreach ($equipos as $eq)  
        <tr class="dato_tabla">
           <td class="center">{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($eq->fecha_adquirido ))}}</td>
           <td class="center"><img src="{{ asset("{$eq->foto }") }}" alt="" class="imgEquiposNew disInline"></td>
           <td style="font-weight: 700!important;" class="noRompe">{{ $eq->refeEquipo }}</td>
           <td style="font-weight: 700!important;" class="noRompe">{{ $eq->nombre }}</td>
           <td class="center">
               <span class="codigoBarras">{{ $eq->serie }}</span>
           </td>
           <td class="center">
              @if ($eq->estado == 0)
                <span class="estadoEquipo">Almacén</span>
              @elseif ($eq->estado == 1)
                <span class="estadoEquipo">Alquiler</span>
              @elseif ($eq->estado == 2)
                <span class="estadoEquipo">Venta</span>
              @elseif ($eq->estado == 3)
                <span class="estadoEquipo">Opción a compra</span>
              @endif
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="{{ route('app.verCliente', $eq->idCliente) }}">{{ $eq->nombreCliente }} {{ $eq->apellidos }} ({{ $eq->empresa }})</a> 
            </td>
            <td>
              /*Aquí quiero imprimir el nombre del centro del asociado
            </td>
           </tr>
          @endforeach
         </tbody>
       </table>
```

Eso me funciona bien, pero si os dais cuenta en la tabla `clientes` hay un campo que se llama `asociado_id` eso significa que el cliente 2 pertenece al primero. Entonces cuando listo los equipos me sale bien el cliente, pero necesito que si el equipo que pertenece a "X" tiene un asociado en la misma fila, quiero imprimir el nombre del centro del asociado.

Eso es de alguna forma posible? En las tablas como podeis ver hay más campos, pero he puesto solo los necesarios.

**Datos que obtengo y necesito**

```
#original: array:25 [▼
    "id" => 21
    "tecnologia_id" => 1
    "referencia" => 4
    "serie" => "32423423"
    "estado" => 1
    "cliente_id" => 601
    "ultima_revision" => null
    "fecha_adquirido" => "2021-05-01"
    "nombre" => "wefwef"
    "limite_garantia_venta" => null
    "tiempo_garantia_venta" => null
    "extension_venta" => 0
    "limite_garantia_alquiler" => null
    "tiempo_garantia_alquiler" => 0
    "extension_alquiler" => 0
    "permanencia" => null
    "created_at" => "2021-05-01 19:45:37"
    "updated_at" => "2021-05-01 20:41:37"
    "nombreCliente" => "Miguel"
    "apellidos" => "Martínez"
    "empresa" => "Miguel empresa"
    "idCliente" => 601 /* Este es el id_cliente que tiene el equipo*/
    "asociado_id" => 594 /* Y este es el distribuidor del cliente 601*/
    "refeEquipo" => "HS-511"
    "foto" => "/storage/photos/1/Equipos/511.png"
  ]
```

Entonces tengo que obtener el nombre del centro de la `id= 594`. Teniendo en cuenta que pueden haber registros que si tienen un asociado y otros no.

**Edición**

---

Esto probando del siguiente modo:

```
$equipos = Equipo::leftjoin('clientes AS cliN', 'equipos.cliente_id', '=', 'cliN.id')
                            ->leftjoin('modelos', 'equipos.referencia', '=', 'modelos.id' )
                            ->leftjoin('clientes AS clie', 'clie.asociado_id', '=', 'cliN.id')
                            ->select('equipos.*', 'cliN.name AS nombreCliente', 'cliN.apellidos', 'cliN.empresa', 'cliN.id AS idCliente', 'cliN.asociado_id', 'modelos.modelo AS refeEquipo', 'modelos.foto', 'clie.centro AS centroDistri')
                            ->get();
```

Vuelvo hacer un `leftjoin` de la tabla clientes para comprobar el `asociado_id` pero sin éxito, me devuelve null. Lo estoy probando en esta linea:

```
->leftjoin('clientes AS clie', 'clie.asociado_id', '=', 'cliN.id')
```

No estaba bien la consulta, cambiando esto funciona perfectamente:

```
->leftjoin('clientes AS clie', 'clie.id', '=', 'cliN.asociado_id')
```

No lo pongo en una respuesta por si a alguien se le ocurre una forma mejor, me parece un poco tediosa así.

**Lo que espero obtener**

| cliente | centro | empresa | distribuidor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nombre del cliente | mi centro | Centro hair remove | Aquí tiene que ir el nombre del centro del asociado |

Realmente obtengo más datos, pero pongo solo unos pocos necesarios.

Comment: No termino de entender del todo el problema, ¿puedes colocar una muestra de los datos de salida que esperas obtener?

Comment: Mira si puedes entenderlo mejor @BetaM , gracias

Comment: Creo que no entendiste del todo como funciona el ORM de Laravel (Eloquent). Hay muy pocos casos en los que tengas que hacer tu los joins a mano y este no es uno de ellos. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: No entiendo, puedes agregar una tabla con los resultados que esperas obtener?

Comment: Hola @ManuelRobles si se más o menos como funciona Eloquent, pero en este caso no sabia si podia hacer una ralación de este modo ya que la relación está en la misma tabla

Comment: Hola @JuanRivera ya actualice poniendo una tabla de lo que espero obterner. En mi misma pregunta hay una solución que encontre "no se si correcta, pero funciona". Si no lo entiendes bien, me lo comentas y te explico mejor. Gracias!

Comment: No hay problemas en tener relaciones a la misma tabla, por lo que se trata como una relacion normal y corriente

Comment: Pues no he sabido como utilizar Eloquent en una misma tabla :S @ManuelRobles